# When and where to place code for pulsating buttons?

Tags: android, firebase, button

I have an 2 apps on different devices - rider and a driver.

I am just about finished my app and to make it easier for the users, I want to have the buttons to pulse when its ok to press that button but I am not sure how, when and where to place to code to activate the pulseAnimation() method.

For example, the btnPay button.  I want it to pulse when it's time to make their payment.  In my app, once the request has been accepted by the driver (driver app), then the btnPay button (rider app) should start pulsating.

How can I do this?

I am also using Firebase as my database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store a variable like 0 or 1 into Firebase, for example `buttonenabled  = 0`

and in your code get the value with `ValueEventListener`

```
if(yourFirebaseValue == 0)
btn.setEnabled(false);
else
btn.setEnabled(true);
```

To apply that pseudocode from above do the following

```
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    //Here get the value at your ref, either 0 or 1
    int needsToAnimate = dataSnapshot.getValue();

    if(needsToAnimate==0){
        //do not animate
    }else{
       //animate your button
     }

  }

  @Override
  public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    System.out.println("The read failed: " + databaseError.getCode());
  }
});
```

Comment: so that would just enable it wouldn't it?  I have it so that it is disabled after all is done on the onclick.  But what i want it to do, is once the driver responds to the requests and it is "accepted" then the PayNow button starts its animation and stops once payment is made.

Comment: you can use the same principle as this to approach your requirement

Comment: ok, i will give this a try and if it works i will accept your answer.  thanks for the response :)

Comment: Would the above code go inside the onclick?  I wouldn't think so, cause i would want it to pulse or flash so the user knows when to click on it.,.. i have tried different areas inside the on create and it still doesn't flash or pulse